# Migrations Add Column after specified column and index column

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to add column via migrations after a certain column also index it (Normal mysql index not unique index). Is this possible via sequelize.js  via migrations. If yes how and if no any alternatives for this via migrations.

Can we execute custom query in sequelize migrations.

Below is my existing migration file.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.addColumn('UserDetails', 'user_id', {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    });
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.removeColumn('UserDetails', 'user_id');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 63):

You can pass `after` or `before` in the options to add column after some specified column.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
return queryInterface.addColumn('UserDetails', 'user_id', {
  type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  after: "some_column"
});
},

down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
return queryInterface.removeColumn('UserDetails', 'user_id');
}
};
```

P.S. 
`after` option is only supported by MySQL
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/query-interface.js#L495

Comment: What version of Sequelize was this working in? I'm on CLI version 3.9.1 and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Frustrating this is not flagged as the answer, it was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Vivek!

Comment: `after` worked great. I tried `before` and didn't have luck. But yes, I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: It was really helpfull, don't believe official [doc](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-addColumn) it's  incorrect. Also accept this as answer

Comment: @Blackjack this is meant for MySQL only. You can actually check the query-interface and see what's the possibility for SQL Server.

Comment: @FreddyDaniel The doc link is broken. This is the new one: [DOC](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-addColumn)

Comment: This one only works on MySQL not for PostgreSQL i guess..

Comment: MySQL supports the after option, but PostgreSQL and SQLite doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way of doing it via `addColumn` function.

But you can do it via raw SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE UserDetails CHANGE COLUMN user_id user_id VARCHAR(50) AFTER some_column;
```

You can run custom SQL queries in migrations like this:

```
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.query("ALTER TABLE UserDetails CHANGE COLUMN user_id user_id VARCHAR(50) AFTER some_column;")
  },
  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return true;
  }
};
```

Since you are already using custom SQL you could add the new column via raw SQL and put it after the column you choosed:

```
ALTER TABLE UserDetails ADD COLUMN user_id VARCHAR(50) AFTER some_column;
```

Comment: FYI, for now in PostgreSQL still issue with 'AFTER' clause is not supported althought use raw SQL query. I get message ERROR: syntax error at or near "AFTER"